# Firebase offline database

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline

My app has a directory which uses firebase to store and update data . I want to show already cached data if the app is kill and started again without being online .

Does firebase delete cache when the app is killed ?

Can we push offline data first irrespective of user being online or offline .

Comment: Firebase has two databases: the older Realtime Database, which stores data in a JSON structure, and the newer Firestore, which stores data in documents and collections. Which of these are you asking about?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you help me . I cannot seem to understand where my code is not functioning right . here is the code i am using in my app to call real time database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my answer on Slack Firebase Community:

setPersistenceEnabled(true) on your database must be the very first thing you do before using any references to call data. Your fetchData() method runs before you call this so setting persistence will fail. You can check for the success of setting persistence like so:

```
bool _success = await globals.firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

You should also run this after setting persistence:

```
_success =
        await globals.firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(10000000);
```

Creating an instance of your database and setting persistence needs to be done as early as possible in the app...so way back in main.dart ideally. (edited)

When hot reloading, the success bool will show false but that is because persistence can only be set successfully once and it was done when the app loaded initially. (edited)

Hope that fixes your problem.

keepSynced(true/false) can then be used for specific bits of the the db to ensure that the specific reference is always current. You can turn this on and off as you wish. keepSynced basically  just adds a listener. If you are already creating listeners for these areas of the db then you don't need keepSynced. (edited)

ps. 'globals' in the code above is just a reference to my global_config.dart file.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you enable offline mode, the data will be cached to disk, so will be available even after the app is killed. Then, when you listen on that same path again, the data will be retrieved, even if the user was offline.

For the Realtime Database (which I assume is what you are talking about), persistence is available for both Android and iOS. There is no offline persistence for web.

On Android:

```java
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

On iOS:

```swift
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
```

Comment: Tried it , but unable to get the desired results . When online the database is getting called perfectly . But when app is killed in restarted in offline without internet the data does not load .

Comment: @NikeshBhansali You can't really guarantee exactly what will be cached and what won't be. This feature is mainly designed for brief periods of connectivity loss, rather than being a full-fledged 'offline mode'. If that is what you really want, you're probably best implementing your own caching mechanism with CoreData/Realm.

Comment: Actually the database needs to be online and will be frequently updated but just wanted to setup a fall back in case the connectivity is not there . Can we force firebase to cache whole file . Also to load offline first so that user does not see any empty page